# HR divider with coloured boxes with sides under an 16 degrees angle

Tags: html, css, angle, divider, horizontal-line

I created a HR divider consisting of several coloured boxed which animate on hover, as shown on this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hagelslag1001/pen/NWzaKPG). Now I want to add 16 degrees angles to the sides of these boxes except for the outermost two sides. Similar to the boxes in this image [image: angled boxes]

I tried clip-path, but it leaves white space between adjacent boxes. I'm stuck in a moment and I can't get out of it. Can anyone give me pointers to tackle this problem?

I use the following CSS code to create the hr divider with hover animation:

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 5px 0px 60px 0px;
}

.box-sm {
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Growing the width of box, when hover using flex-grow property*/
.box-sm:hover {
  flex-grow: 12;
}

.bluewh1 {
  background-color: #4594d3;
}

.bluewh2 {
  background-color: #1ebcc5;
}

.bluewh3 {
  background-color: #84d0d9;
}
```

In the HTML file the divider is added as follows:

```
<div class="box drop-shadow2">
   <div class="box-sm bluewh1"></div>
   <div class="box-sm bluewh2"></div>
   <div class="box-sm bluewh3"></div>
   <div class="box-sm bluewh2"></div>
   <div class="box-sm bluewh1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) rather than multiple boxes? For example: https://jsfiddle.net/gom3Ly9u/

Comment: @DavidThomas I did not consider that yet. Can one still use the hover effect after using the linear-gradient (..)?